# Conversion of string dictionary with single quoted values to double quoted values

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, replace

Given a dictionary represented as a string with keys and values single-quoted. I'm not good with regular expressions, so I want to know if it is possible to convert the keys and values in the string to double-quoted. The reason for this is to parse the string as a dictionary type in other to extract the keys and values pair.

Below is an example illustrating my challenge

```
Initial as string:
{'first_name': 'John', 'age': 89}

Final as string:
{"first_name": "John", "age": 89}
```

I don't know if regex is possible or any other method.
Please help me out

Comment: Why not use `ast.literal_eval()`? It understands both single and double quotes, just like regular Python does.

Comment: Replacing the quotes won't work well if there are embedded double quotes, you'll get invalid JSON.

Comment: Let me try, I haven't used that before

Comment: Why didnt you just produce valid JSON in the first place?

Comment: I'm creating a user input console using cmd. And I want to run a testcase if the user passes in a dictionary (string) with single and double quotes. So, to get the keys and values in dictionary format from the input. Single double and single quoted words are strings, they should work. That why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your example string isn't valid JSON, it *is* valid for a python dictionary; so, you can get away with simply using [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) [at least for this particular string].

```py
dictStr = '''{'first_name': "John", "age": 89}'''

dictObj = eval(dictStr)
print('dictObj:', type(dictObj), repr(dictObj), '\n')

# import json
jsonStr = json.dumps(eval(dictStr))
print('jsonStr:', type(jsonStr), repr(jsonStr), '\n')
```

should print

> ```py
> dictObj: <class 'dict'> {'first_name': 'John', 'age': 89} 
>
> jsonStr: <class 'str'> '{"first_name": "John", "age": 89}'
> ```

`jsonStr` is exactly what your title is asking for, but I think your end goal is `dictObj` which you probably though you need `jsonStr` for [but in this case you don't need it, since you can get the dictionary directly with needing to fix the JSON.]

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval` when the *safe* `ast.literal_eval` will do the trick. The OP is accepting user input; passing it to `eval` is asking for trouble, but `ast.literal_eval` can't do anything insane.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "Safer", not safe. The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) also doesn't call it safe anymore.